# Why can't I see the visitor post in the sidebar

Tags: facebook

I do not see the Visitor Posts section in the sidebar of my business Facebook page. https://www.facebook.com/KidsFMN/

How can I get that to display?

Answer (score 0):

On the menu bar of your Facebook page (ie Home, About, Photos, Events), click on "Community" (it may be under the "More") menu option.

This will show the visitor posts to your page.